# Compile/transpile code while developing React app

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, webpack, gulp

I am developing an app in React.

Until now I have just included

```
<script src='//unpkg.com/react@15/dist/react.min.js'>
<script src='//unpkg.com/react-dom@15/dist/react-dom.min.js'>
<script src='//unpkg.com/babel-standalone@6/babel.min.js'>
```

and then I neither had to use

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
```

since everything was loaded nor had to compile anything since babel compiled it in real-time.

However, when I want to include third-party libraries installed with npm, it seems I have to use import. For instance, if I install `react-dates` with `npm-install react-dates --save` and want to include it with

```
import { DateRangePicker, SingleDatePicker, DayPickerRangeController } from 'react-dates';
```

I get the error

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined
```

I guess it's because I don't use RequireJS, Webpack, Gulp or anything.

What is the preferred way to be able to include components while developing, so I don't have to compile my code everytime I did a small change?

Comment: I guess you can carry on using unpkg for react-dates as well while prototyping. Instead of installing via `npm`, just include more `script` tags as you did for react & co. More info here: https://unpkg.com/#/

Comment: I have found https://unpkg.com/react-dates@12.0.0 but it has a lot of `require` statements which doesn't seem to work in the browser

Comment: That particular module doesn't publish the browser module (the version you need) on npm, therefore unpkg will send you the main module. Either you find an alternative module with browser bundle available or you setup a local bundler (Webpack/RollUp/etc...).

Comment: Or you can use create-react-app which does all the setup for you, and add the module.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `webpack` to configure your code, and run it in `watch` mode or use 
`webpack-dev-server` during development so, that will allow you to compile your code automatically any time you do a small change

Your `webpack.config.js` should look something like

```
var debug=process.env.NODE_ENV !== "production";
var path=require("path");
var webpack=require("webpack");

module.exports = {
    context: path.join(__dirname, "src"),
    devtool: debug ? "inline-sourcemap" : null,
    entry: "./js/index.js",
    module: {
        rules: [{
            test: /\.jsx?$/,
            exclude: [/node_modules/],
            use: [{
                loader: "babel-loader",
                options: {presets: ["stage-0","es2015","react"]}
            }]

        }]
    },
    output: {
        path: __dirname + "/src",
        filename: "bundle.js"
    },
    plugins: debug? [] : [
        new webpack.optimize.DedupePlugin(),
        new webpack.optimize.OccurenceOrderPlugin(),
        new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({mangle: false, sourcemap: false})
    ]
}
```

And in your package.json, you can define scripts

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "webpack-dev-server --content-base src",
    "build": "webpack --watch"

  }
```

If you run a `npm run build` command `webpack` will start in watch mode and you won't need to recompile your code again and again.

or you can run `npm start` for using `webpack-dev-server` in development mode.

See how to set up webpack **[here](https://blog.madewithenvy.com/getting-started-with-webpack-2-ed2b86c68783)**